# Run a python script on Azure shared hosting

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET C# web application deployed on Azure web sites(shared hosting). Is it possible that I could execute a python script from .NET code on Azure shared hosting?

Any help with be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, there is a site extension for Azure WebApp called `Python Installer` you can use when you turn off Python in the Azure Portal, please access `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/?#gallery` to search `Python` to install it, as below.

[image]

You can try to refer to its GitHub [README](https://github.com/davidebbo/PythonSiteExtension) to know how to get started.